# Профайлы в React

Tags: reactjs, profile

У меня такой вопрос, я пытаюсь понять, как запустить react приложение(созданное через create-react-app) c разными профайлами.
То есть, допустим у меня есть несколько окружений(local, dev, prod) и у меня есть fetch, который обращается на backend(который развернут на другом сервере). И у backend есть свои адрес для каждого окружения. То есть мне нужно как-то установить глобально переменную, которую я давать fetch и все будет работать. например в Springboot это можно делать через application-"profile".properties. Запускаю я приложение через npm install -g serve & serve -s build. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете обратиться к переменной окружения `NODE_ENV`, и проверять ее состояние:

```
const serverUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? 'http://localhost:4000'
        : 'http://youdomain.com:4000'
```

Или использовать компонент `dotenv`, и создать файл `.env`, в него записать все необходимые переменные окружения, например

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = XXX-YYY-ZZZ.apps.googleusercontent.com
REACT_APP_API_PROTOCOL = http:
REACT_APP_API_HOST = localhost:3000
NODE_PATH = src/scripts
PORT = 9001
```

А потом запускать

```
"start": "react-scripts start dotenv_config_path=.env",
"build": "react-scripts build dotenv_config_path=.env.production",
```

И ваше переменные будут свойствами объекта `process.env`

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Для того, чтобы это организовать нужно в корень проекта добавить два файла:

.env

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_DOMAIN=http://localhost:8080
```

.env.production

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_DOMAIN=http://app.com
```

и после этого в коде в нужном месте достаете переменную process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_DOMAIN:

```
return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_DOMAIN + '/topics', {
    method: 'GET'
}).then((response) => response.json());
```

При локальном запуске npm run react достанет переменную с файла .env.
При продакшн запуске serve -s build, react достанет переменную уже с файла .env.production.